# Why does QChar( Qt::Key_Right ) now segfault?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt6, qchar

I am updating some old cold from a project known as QFakeVim, and it is taking keyboard inputs as integers, and then returning QChar's based on that integer. That is not particularly important other than the fact that this code used to be functional. I am not sure however what has changed since Qt6 in regards to QChar.

To replicate the bug, one merely needs this line of code:

```cpp
QChar( Qt::key_Right );
```

which is calling this line of code:

```cpp
constexpr QCHAR_MAYBE_IMPLICIT QChar(int rc) noexcept : QChar(uint(rc)) {}
// which calls:
constexpr QCHAR_MAYBE_IMPLICIT QChar(uint rc) noexcept : ucs((Q_ASSERT(rc <= 0xffff), char16_t(rc))) {}
```

Which is failing this:

```cpp
Q_ASSERT(rc <= 0xffff)
```

Did something change in Qt6 regarding this? Why does it wish to Q_ASSERT here? Thanks.

Comment: `Qt::Key_Right` is `0x01000014` that is greater than `0xffff`. `QChar` wants getting UTF16 symbol but gets the keypad code.

Comment: @273K I know it does. I'm asking why this code was placed here. What is its purpose? What is it protecting?

Comment: It's protecting against things like implicitly converting a `Qt::Key` enum to a `QChar` which is a totally invalid conversion.

Comment: @paddy Good enough for me. Was it like that before?

Comment: By "it" and "before", are you referring to the actual code prompting your question, which you have not shown us?